# validate_on_submit is not working using WTF Forms

Tags: validation, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

When I registered on the page, I see that are the values getting inserted into the database and it is redirecting me to the Login function as mentioned in the code, but I don't understand why the login page itself is getting redirected every time I tried to login, instead, it should get redirected to the chat function.

[I see that index function is working clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQg0g.png)

[and also the values are getting inserted into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiZ07.png)

[But when I tried to login it's not getting redirected to the chat page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCFJi.png)

When I printed "login_form.validate_on_submit", it is always resulting false, so I could see that there is something wrong with the validate_on_submit function, but I'm not getting what it is.

This is my Login Function inside application.py:

```
@app.route('/login',methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    login_form=LoginForm()
    print(login_form)
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        user_object=User.query.filter_by(username=login_form.username.data)
        login_user(user_object)
        return redirect(url_for("chat"))
    return render_template("login.html", form=login_form)
```

This is WTForm_Fields.py:

```
def invalid_credentials(form, field):
    """ Username and password checker """

    password = field.data
    username = form.username.data

    # Check username is invalid
    user_data = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    print(user_data)
    if user_data is None:
        raise ValidationError("Username or password is incorrect")

    # Check password in invalid
    elif not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, user_data.hashed_pswd):
        raise ValidationError("Username or password is incorrect")

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    """login form"""
    username=StringField('username_label',validators=[InputRequired(message="username required")])
    password=PasswordField('password_label',validators=[InputRequired(message="Password Required"),invalid_credentials])
```

This is login.html:

```
{% from 'form_helper.html' import displayField %}
{% extends 'prelogin-template.html'%}

{%block title%}Login{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
    <h2>Login now!</h2>
    <p>Enter your username/Password to start!!</p>

    <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}",method='POST'>
        {{displayField(form.username,"Username",autocomplete='off',autofocus=true)}}
        {{displayField(form.password,"Password")}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-warning">
        </div>
        {{ form.crsf_token }}

    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

This is prelogin-template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{%block title%}{%endblock%}-Let's Chat </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    {% with messages=get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}    
            Category:{{ messages[0][0] }}
            {{messages[0][1]}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {%block content%}
    
    {%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

This is form_helper.html:

```
{% macro displayField(fieldName,placeholderValue) %}
<div class='form-group'>
   {{fieldName(class="form_control",placeholder=placeholderValue,**kwargs)}}
    <ul class="formError">
       {% for error in fieldName.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: You can try printing {{form.errors}} below the form tag in html to see what is the error when you submit.

Comment: I did that in the form helper template, and it is showing errors for the index template if I do something wrong, but not for the login template, I've added the code for form_helper, please check.

Comment: You should add that in login.html above this line `{{displayField(form.username,"Username",autocomplete='off',autofocus=true)}}` or add that in app.py in login function above this `return render_template("login.html", form=login_form)`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are **no problems in** your **form_helper.html, prelogin-template.html, login.html and WTForm_Fields.py** files. However, there is **an issue** in your **Login Function**. I think that Database query error has occurred. One suggestion is to simply add **.first()** at the end of the user object. flask_login sometimes does not log a user in when you provide **flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object** as the parameter.

Try doing this in **Login Function** inside application.py:

```
@app.route('/login',methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    login_form=LoginForm()
    print(login_form)
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        user_object=User.query.filter_by(username=login_form.username.data).first() #<--add here
        login_user(user_object)
        return redirect(url_for("chat"))
    return render_template("login.html", form=login_form)
```

This should smoothly log a user in.